# C# & SQL Server : deadlock in parallel transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server, parallel-processing, transactions, unit-of-work

I am testing a custom `UnitOfWork` class with `System.Data.SqlClient` objects, I need it to manage possible concurrent transaction and db connection for some simple ado.net operations.

I have a deadlock between the first or third complete executions, in the second select in class Repo1 or Repo2, the one after the insert command.

This happens even even with "Serializable" isolation level.

I expect that, even in separate task, the program could execute all transaction without conflicts, in a way that every transaction is enqueued in a random order, but maybe I'm just using the wrong isolation level.

My intention is the following

- in the same transaction: do a select on the table after an insert and I expect to get the value inserted in the previous command on the same transaction.
- in commands outside this transaction: I expect that a select reads the actual committed values ignoring, the uncommitted values

This is my code

```
public class AdoNetUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    SqlConnection _connection;
    bool _ownsConnection;
    SqlTransaction _transaction;

    public AdoNetUnitOfWork(SqlConnection connection, bool ownsConnection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _ownsConnection = ownsConnection;
        _transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    }

    public SqlCommand CreateCommand()
    {
        var command = _connection.CreateCommand();
        command.Transaction = _transaction;
        return command;
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        if (_transaction == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Transaction have already been commited. Check your transaction handling.");

        _transaction.Commit();
        _transaction = null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_transaction != null)
        {
            _transaction.Rollback();
            _transaction = null;
        }

        if (_connection != null && _ownsConnection)
        {
            _connection.Close();
            _connection = null;
        }
    }
}

public class UnitOfWorkFactory
{
    public static AdoNetUnitOfWork Create()
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(
            "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=False;User Id=**;Password=***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True");
        connection.Open();

        return new AdoNetUnitOfWork(connection, true);
    }
}
```

Business logic class:

```
public class Service
{
    public Service()
    {
    }

    public OutputStr MakeCalls()
    {
        using (var uow = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            var repo1 = new Repo1(uow);
            repo1.ExecuteQuery(out int idStart1, out int idEnd1);

            var repo2 = new Repo2(uow);
            repo2.ExecuteQuery(out int idStart2, out int idEnd2);

            OutputStr str = new OutputStr()
                                { 
                                    IdStart1 = idStart1, IdEnd1 = idEnd1,
                                    IdStart2 = idStart2, IdEnd2 = idEnd2
                                };

            uow.SaveChanges();

            return str;
        }
    }
}

public class OutputStr
{
    public int IdStart1 { get; set; }
    public int IdEnd1 { get; set; }
    public int IdStart2 { get; set; }
    public int IdEnd2 { get; set; }
}
```

Query execution class on table 1:

```
public class Repo1
{
    AdoNetUnitOfWork _uow;

    public Repo1(AdoNetUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public void ExecuteQuery(out int idStart, out int idEnd)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = _uow.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Id),0) from Table1";
        idStart = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        cmd.CommandText = @"
            INSERT INTO Table1
               ([Id])
               SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Id),0)+1 
                from Table1";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Id),0) from Table1";
        idEnd = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        //idEnd = 0;
    }
}
```

Script to create table1:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
(
    [Id] [INT] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Query execution class2

```
public class Repo2
{
    AdoNetUnitOfWork _uow;

    public Repo2(AdoNetUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public void ExecuteQuery(out int idStart, out int idEnd)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = _uow.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Id),0) from Table2";
        idStart = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Table2 ([Id])
                                SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Id),0)+1 
                                FROM Table2";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(Id), 0) FROM Table2";
        idEnd = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        //idEnd = 0;
    }
}
```

Script to create table 2

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2]
(
    [Id] [INT] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Console class

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Service svc = new Service();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Current call {i}");
            new Task(() => Printer(svc, i)).Start();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Printer(Service svc, int index)
    {
        OutputStr str = svc.MakeCalls();
        Console.WriteLine($@"
            start1:{str.IdStart1}, end1:{str.IdEnd1}, 
            start2:{str.IdStart2}, end2:{str.IdEnd2}");
    }
}
```

EDIT: solved using this command on database

```
SELECT is_read_committed_snapshot_on, snapshot_isolation_state_desc,snapshot_isolation_state 
FROM sys.databases WHERE name='db'

ALTER DATABASE db SET allow_snapshot_isolation ON
ALTER DATABASE db SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
ALTER DATABASE db SET read_committed_snapshot ON
ALTER DATABASE db SET MULTI_USER

SELECT is_read_committed_snapshot_on, snapshot_isolation_state_desc,snapshot_isolation_state 
FROM sys.databases WHERE name='db'
```

And changing code to

```
_transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Snapshot);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
My intention is the following:
 -in the same transaction: do a select on the table after an insert and I expect to get the value inserted in the prevous command on the same transaction.
 -in commands outside this transaction: i expect that a select reads the actual committed values ignoring, the uncommitted values
```

Then you should use the READ_COMMITTED (default) isolation level in a database with the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT option set ON.
eg

```
alter database current set read_committed_snapshot on
```

See [Snapshot Isolation In SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server)

Comment: thanks a lot, with both code and database isolation changed to "snapshot" there are no deadlock. 

Now is only a matter of handling correctly the code.

I was also worried that the deadlock problem was caused by vars of type System.Data.SqlClient in the unit of work, but it was not the case.